# Improve this O(N) linear search to O(log N) time complexity

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve this [Geeks for Geeks problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/element-appearing-once2552/1):

> #### Find the element that appears once
>
> Given a sorted array A[] of N positive integers having all the numbers occurring exactly twice, except for one number which will occur only once. Find the number occurring only once.
>
> **Your Task:**
> You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function search() which takes two arguments(array A and integer N) and returns the number occurring only once.
>
> **Expected Time Complexity:** O(Log(N)).
> **Expected Auxiliary Space:** O(1).
>
> **Constraints**
> 0 < N <= 10^6
> 0 <= A[i] <= 10^9

My approach:

> For Given `Array:A` & `Size:N`
> Initialize i With 0 `i=0` # i is index reference in array traversal
> loop through `0 to N-1`# While i<N :
> Select `i^th`element from `Array :A`# select=A[i]
> Creates A  Sub-array(next) does not contain `select` # next=A[i+1:] 
> Now compare the `next` (sub-array) with `select` 
> If it contains a duplicate/copy of `select` 
> Push `select` to a **new sub-array**(`previous`) # previous keep record of visted element
> Update `i to +1` & repeat this process
> next tym **new value** get selected in`i` as `select=A[i+1]` 
> Check if it exist in **sub-array** `next`&& 
> If The `previous` **sub array** also  not contained `select`#Hopefully it is traversed first tym  and it is **unique**
> return the `i^th` element which doesn't inside both `previous` and `next` sub-array

Code:

```
# Function to recognize singular element i

def check(list,n):
 i=0
 select=0
 next=0
 previous=[]
 while(i<n):
  select=list[i]
  next=list[i+1:]
  if select in next:
    previous.append(select)
  elif select in previous:
    pass
  else:
   return select
  i+=1
  



# Driver Code
def main():
 list=[]
 n =int(input('Enter Size of array:'))
 for a in range(0,n):
  x=int(input('Array[{}]='.format(a)))
  list.append(x)
 i=check(list,n)
 print('The No.is :',i)

main()
```

The above script works but is not O(log N). I tried removing extra variable and converted extra sub-array to variable to reduce time.

Comment: You have omitted some important details.  The array is sorted, and all elements bar one appear twice.  This means all numbers will be pairs, either starting at odd or even location depending on whether the single number has appeared.  Try binary search based on this.

Comment: Interesting enough, I come to the same idea as @PeterdeRivaz, and just tried it out in the platform, but got 1.4 sec (failed.)  So I use bit tricks, and this time it's passed (0.3 sec)!  Hint: x^x == 0  (the single num will surface...)

Comment: 1) Can you think of a rule that tells you the mathematical relationship between the indices of the paired numbers i) that appear before the unique number; ii) that appear after the unique number? 2) if you look at three which is (regardless of the array size, so that's O(1)) adjacent numbers, can you prove that either two of them are a pair (the remaining one might be unique), or the middle one is the unique one? iii) If two of the values were a pair, given i), you can see whether they are before or after the unique value. Think of a way to use this information to guide a *binary search*.